# Can Factory Reset delete a virus?

Tags: malware, antivirus

In my **Lenovo A536** phone a malicious app that is alarm controller and calendar service is unknowingly installed and it is creating a problem.

I am not able to uninstall the app as it is automatically stored in in-built app.

So can `Factory Reset` remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If the app has installed itself as a system app, then no, factory reset will not remove it. It will just wipe it's data, but it will start installing again, after you boot your phone up.

You will need to flash your device with a stock firmware file, which does not have the virus installed.

You can follow this tutorial:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/tutorial-how-to-flash-lenovo-a536-stock-t3300818

Answer (score 0):

These **are not** viruses. These are *false positives*.

**AlarmController** is a system app that allows your alarms to play, even when the main alarms app is not running.

**CalenderService** does a number of things. It notifies you of calendar events, ensures the system date is (relatively) accurate, and manages the synchronisation of Calendar data with the cloud.